# Can i replicate the user click action on a button in microsoft teams using microsoft graph api?

Tags: click, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have added a custom bot to Microsoft teams channel and I am trying to do test automation for this bot using Microsoft graph API. I was able to send text messages to a bot in a team's channel by following the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.
I want to know if it is possible to replicate user click action on a button using graph APIs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

UX manipulation/automation is not possible via Graph nor via the Teams Javascript SDK.

I would suggest using Selenium for testing the web version and the desktop version.

Comment: I am not attempting to click the button but to send a payload that would have been generated when user  clicked a button

Comment: then it would be useful to know [Which button.

Comment: also it would be good to understand why you cant (unit-)test by sending the messages directly to your bot service end-point

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, your 'bot' is basically just a REST web service. To test it, you can send it messages that match the payload that would have been sent from Teams when the user clicked your button. To get this payload, I'd suggest debugging locally using NGrok, and loading the ngrok logging page (http://localhost:4000), which will show you the calls that are made. Capture that call and replay it using a testing harness of some sort, and you would be fine.

However, depending on what you're wanting to test, it might be possible to bypass the web call altogether, and create code that doesn't depend on any bot infrastructure at all (e.g. turnContexts and Activities). That would make your code more testable anyway, and the tests would run much faster.